# Passing a list to a function to be modified

Tags: python, list, function

I'm teaching myself Python out of a book and I am having trouble with this two part exercise. I posted about it yesterday thinking that I had the first part correct but someone pointed out to me that it was not correct so I reworked it and now I think I have the first part correct but am still having trouble with the second part.

**First part of the exercise:**

> Make a list of magician’s names. Pass the list to a function called `show_magicians()`, which prints the name of each magician in the list.

**My code for the first part of the exercise:**

```
def show_magicians(names):
    for name in names:
        print(name)

magicians_names = ['Marv', 'Wowzo', 'Trickster', 'Didlo']

show_magicians(magicians_names)
```

**Output:**

```
Marv
Wowzo
Trickster
Didlo
```

**Second part of the exercise:**

> Start with a copy of your program from Exercise 8-9. Write a function called `make_great()` that modifies the list of magicians by add- ing the phrase the Great to each magician’s name. Call `show_magicians()` to see that the list has actually been modified.

**My code for the second part of the exercise:**

```
def show_magicians(names):
    for name in names:
        print(name)

def make_great():


magicians_names = ['Marv', 'Wowzo', 'Trickster', 'Didlo']

show_magicians(magicians_names)
```

**My Question:**
For starters I need to know if I did the first part correctly. I think I did but I could be wrong. As far as the second part I've tried a few things for the make_great function but I am really at a loss as to what I need to do to get it to modify the list. I think it has something to do with a while loop but I'm really not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your first function does what is should.  `make_great()` will require going through each index of the list, and changing the list at that index.  Hint: `range()` is a useful function. :)

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary to use a `while` loop.   You can use a for loop and the `range` function mentioned above.  I'd also suggest looking into the `len` function so you can get the size of the list programatically.

Comment: You could even use a list comprehension with `magicians_names` as the resulting list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing something like this:

```
def show_magicians(names):
    for name in names:
        print(name)

def make_great(magicians_names):
    return [ name + ' The Great' for name in magicians_names ]

magicians_names = ['Marv', 'Wowzo', 'Trickster', 'Didlo']

magicians_names = make_great(magicians_names)
show_magicians(magicians_names)
```

Another option is to modify the list in place:

```
def show_magicians(names):
    for name in names:
        print(name)

def make_great(magicians_names):
    for i in range(len(magicians_names)):
        magicians_names[i] += ' The Great'

magicians_names = ['Marv', 'Wowzo', 'Trickster', 'Didlo']

make_great(magicians_names)
show_magicians(magicians_names)
```

Comment: I believe this is the solution I've been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you really do want to modify the list, as opposed to creating a new list:

```
def make_great(magicians_names):
    for j in range(len(magicians_names)):
        magicians_names[j] = 'The Great ' + magicians_names[j]
    return magicians_names
```